# Use printf with args into variadic functions?

Tags: c, printf, variadic, c89

I need a function that works like `printf`, but makes some changes to the `fmt` string: for example, add at the beginning a string containing the datetime, but the rest, I will maintain the same `printf` stuff...

```
void simple_printf(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    va_end(args);

    /* made some changes to fmt, concatenate string,...*/

    printf(fmt, ...);
}
```

Here is the code I'm making. As you can see, I wish to change the `fmt` string, but after, call the 'standard' `printf` or `sprintf`, passing the parameters — a sort of bypass.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you enter e.g. `va_list printf` in your favorite search engine it should be pretty easy to find out about the `vprintf` function. And any decent book or tutorial about variadic arguments and function should really have mentioned it as well.

Comment: Note that the `va_end` will be after the `vprintf()`.

Comment: ghiboz, Yes it is possible.

Comment: I would not change the format string, but use extra `printf()` to add before and/or after the caller's requested output. -- You might want to [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: Note that C89 did not standardize `vprintf()`, `vsprintf()`, `vfprintf()` et al.  However, some C89 implementations provide those functions anyway, or provide surrogates (equivalents) with a different name.  Remember: C89 is over 30 years old — it is ancient and has been superseded by C99, C11, C18.  You should not be programming to C89 without a very good reason.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My copy of ANSI X3.159-1989 clearly documents `vprintf`, `vfprintf`, and `vsprintf`.  (Maybe you were thinking of the missing `vscanf` family?)

Comment: @SteveSummit — you're right, my bad.  What C89 doesn't have is `snprintf()` and `vsnprintf()` — those arrived in C99.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways of doing this.  You can find some of my code that does this sort of thing in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  That's a package I've developed over many years (the earliest version I still have a record for dates to 1988) and I use it in most of my C programs.

The scheme used now ensures that there's a single write operation by converting the data to be formatted into a string — see `err_fmtmsg()` — and then using the appropriate writing mechanism (standard I/O such as [`fprintf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html), or
[`write()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html), or [`syslog()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/syslog.html)) to send the message to the output mechanism.

```c
static size_t err_fmtmsg(char *buffer, size_t buflen, int flags, int errnum,
                         const char *format, va_list args)
{
    char *curpos = buffer;
    char *bufend = buffer + buflen;

    buffer[0] = '\0';   /* Not strictly necessary */
    if ((flags & ERR_NOARG0) == 0)
        curpos = efmt_string(curpos, bufend, "%s: ", arg0);
    if (flags & ERR_LOGTIME)
    {   
        char timbuf[32];
        curpos = efmt_string(curpos, bufend,
                             "%s - ", err_time(flags, timbuf, sizeof(timbuf)));
    }   
    if (flags & ERR_PID)
        curpos = efmt_string(curpos, bufend,
                             "pid=%d: ", (int)getpid());
    curpos = vfmt_string(curpos, bufend, format, args);
    if (flags & ERR_ERRNO)
        curpos = efmt_string(curpos, bufend,
                             "error (%d) %s\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    assert(curpos >= buffer);
    return((size_t)(curpos - buffer));
}
```

As you may be able to see, this can prefix the message produced by `arg0` (the program name, set via a function `err_setarg0()`; it can add a PID; it can add the timestamp (with options for integral seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds under control of the flags), and can append the error number and corresponding system error message too.

This is a function hidden in the bowels of the system.  At the external level, one of the entry points is `extern void err_syserr(const char *fmt, ...);` — this automatically adds the system error, prints the message on standard error, and exits the program.  There are a wide variety of other entry points for logging, some of which exit and some return.  And there are a lot of controls too.

Note that the `err_fmtmsg()` function takes an argument `va_list args`.  This is normally the best way to work.  You should write your code using this scheme:

```
void simple_printf(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    simple_vprintf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}

void simple_vprintf(const char* fmt, va_list args)
{
    /* … preamble … */
    vprintf(fmt, args);
    /* … postamble … */
}
```

You write the main function using the `va_list` function and provide a convenience interface using `...` that calls on the main function, as shown above.

If you are going to use multiple calls to standard I/O writing functions (`fprintf()` et al), then consider using [`flockfile()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html)
and `funlockfile()` to keep the outputs 'atomic'.

```c
void simple_vprintf(const char* fmt, va_list args)
{
    flockfile(stdout);
    /* … preamble — possibly writing to stdout … */
    vprintf(fmt, args);
    /* … postamble — possibly writing to stdout … */
    funlockfile(stdout);
}
```

You'd also consider providing functions like these:

```
extern void simple_fprintf(FILE *fp, const char *fmt, ...);
extern void simple_vfprintf(FILE *fp, const char *fmt, va_list args);
```

Then `simple_vprintf()` would simply invoke `simple_vfprintf(stdout, fmt, args)`.  You might then start looking at `static inline` implementations of the cover functions in the header file.

After a while, if you implement enough variations, you're starting to encroach on the implementation found in `stderr.[ch]`.

Comment: Doesn't printf already do the flockfile business?

Comment: Yes, but if you are going to make multiple calls on the same I/O stream and want them all grouped together, using the explicit locks ensures that the operations in the preamble and postamble are grouped with the main operation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `printf`, you should call `vprintf` from your variadic function:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void simple_printf(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    int d = (t - 746755200) / 86400;
    int h = (t %= 86400) / 3600;
    int m = (t %= 3600) / 60;
    int s = t % 60;

    /* output a timestamp at the beginning of the line, thank you Janice Brandt */
    printf("Sep %d, 1993 %02d:%02d:%02d UTC: ", d, h, m, s);

    /* no changes should be made to fmt because it is a constant string */
    vprintf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: Picking a nit — the code should not modify the string that `fmt` points to because it is `const char *fmt`.  What could be valid is modifying a copy of what `fmt` points at — and possibly making `fmt` point to the modified copy.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: good point. Answer amended with a reference to [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September), a memory that lives on at https://www.eternal-september.org/